# Using canvas to achieve a responsive animated background?

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I'm building a site where I need it to be split into 2 rows, one side that stays fixed, which is my canvas animation, and another that scrolls, this is where all the info is.

My set up is something like this:

```
<div class="left-canvas-box"><!-- form/content--></div>
<canvas></canvas>
<div class="right-scroll-content"><!-- information content --> </div>
```

I am using a `<canvas></canvas>` that has a `z-index: -1;` to achieve the background effect, but whenever I try to respond it so the divs will stack on top of each other, it only shows one or the other, the white div or the 'clear' div.

(the fiddle has complete code)

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dLu3qkor/4/

using this code in the phone-size query achieves only the right-side content being static and un scrollable.

```
.left-canvas-box, .right-scroll-content{
width: 100%;
float: none;
display: block;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the desired effect is.

Comment: It's alright, I figured it out, will post in an answer for anyone who may need this type of effect. It's basically a fake parallax.

Comment: what do think of code now ? http://jsfiddle.net/dLu3qkor/15/